# How to disable geolocation permissions for a website using firefox capabilities in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I want to disable the geolocation permissions for a website using firefox capabilities in selenium webdriver, but i am not able to do so.

I tried doing this...

```
WebDriver d = null;
cap = cap.merge(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("geo.enabled", false);
cap.setCapability("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
cap.setCapability("geo.prompt.testing", false);
cap.setCapability("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);
```

Attached is the screenshot of the same

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with your specific parameter but for others it works well, like this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();  
// Turn off updates
profile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Using Selenium 2.48 and FF 42.0 (but it should do for other versions, as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
caps.setCapability("locationContextEnabled", false);
```